# Is there an equivalent to Swift's keypath feature in Python?

Tags: python

In Swift, you can use a language feature called *keypaths* to generate a function that accesses a property of an object. For example,

```
// Swift

categories.map { category in category.name }

// could also be written as...

categories.map(\.name)
```

In Python, I sometimes find myself writing out code like:

```
# Python
map(lambda cat: cat.name, categories)
```

Is there a shorter way to write `lambda cat: cat.name`, analogous to Swift keypaths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter)

```
from operator import attrgetter

map(attrgetter("cat"), categories)
```

Comment: Thanks! It doesn’t look like it works on object instances though.

Comment: Sorry, for objects it's `attrgetter`.